# Find number of long trades in strategy

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I was trying to access the number of long and short trades taken in a strategy separately but I could not find any function for this. We can find wintrades and losstrades by strategy.wintrades and strategy.losstrades. Is there a similar function for counting longwintrades and shortwintrades?

Tradingview does have this data separated for longs and shorts as it is shown in the performance summary tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use: [https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy{dot}closedtrades{dot}size](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dclosedtrades%7Bdot%7Dsize)

"Returns the direction and the number of contracts traded in the closed trade. If the value is > 0, the market position was long. If the value is < 0, the market position was short."

Exemple: Fetching all the closed long trades

```
for tradeNo = 0 to strategy.closedtrades - 1
     if (strategy.closedtrades.size(tradeNo) > 0) 
enter code here
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This helps. I wish there was a function to call directly :}